# Get pre-signed URL(s3) and render PDF/image on browser

Tags: reactjs, pdf, amazon-s3, fetch

I am new to react, trying to get pre-signed url(s3) which is returned from the API and invoke the pre-signed URL to render the PDF on browser.

I could see two calls on network tab, one call returns 308 and other call returns 200 with response.but not sure why I am not able to get the pre-resigned URL from response, tried response.json and response.text.

How to get the response from the second call (with response status 200) or how to make sure only one call is fired?

How to render the pdf on the browser using iframe or the best way to render pdf?
I did try with hardcoded pre-signed url, it does download the pdf but does not render in iframe.

Thanks for your help in advance. below is the code snippet.

```
const refIframe = useRef(null)
const [data, setData] = useState(null)


useEffect(() => {
   let url =  "http://127.0.0.1:5000/files/1233"
   const fetchData = async () => { fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'no-cors', // 'cors' by default
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            'Content-Type': 'text/html',}
        }).then(response => {
            return response.text()
        }).then(data =>
            setData(data)
        );
    }
    fetchData();
    refIframe.current.setAttribute('src', data);
}, []);


return (
    <div>
        <iframe ref={refIframe} allowFullScreen title={'PDF Viewer'} />
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Don't leave dangling promises, it's a source of bugs which are difficult to spot later. `const fetchData = async () => fetch(...)` or `await` in the body. As per the actual question, move `refIFrame.current.setAttribute(...)` to the last `then` block - it should be just the same `data` as you passed to `setData`.

Comment: I did try moving the refIFrame.current.setAttribute(...) inside the last then but data is coming as empty so empty iframe rendered. As I stated , the fetch fires two calls and only the second call has the valid response. former one has 308 response code. how to get the response content from second call?

Comment: 308 is permanent redirect - where does it redirect? If it's fixed (e.g. you're missing trailing slash), just use the target as `fetch` URL. If not - add `redirect: 'follow'` to your `fetch` parameters. Btw, why do you have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in **request** headers? It's a response header that has no effect when sent by te client...

Comment: what is this value? `response.text()`

Comment: response.text() - I am looking to get the signed URL from the API call but it is empty.

Comment: @STerliakov added the trailing slash which resolved the two calls. now only one call but the response data is empty when I printed in console. I could see the response in the network tab. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Removed the *mode: 'no-cors'* (CORS) from the request header and added following in the server response header and now able to get the signed URL. 

```
headers : {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*"      
    }
```

signedURL is set in src attribute of iframe but still does not render the pdf.

Comment: You will have to move "refIframe.current.setAttribute" in the "then" block because if you keep it outside then you are assigning the value before API call is completed. That's the reason nothing will be rendered.

Comment: You said you are expecting to get a signed URL from "response.text()". If it's a signed URL its output won't be "text/html". It should be something in JSON right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to GENERATE a presigned URL from S3 after for the desired object and then use it on your frontend. You can have your BE do this & return the signed url in api response.

With NodeJS as your backend, you can do it like this in your `/files/1233` api route to make a request to s3 to generate one and return the response you received.

```
const params = {
    Bucket: "bucketName",
    Key: "objectKey",
    Expires: "expirationTime in seconds",
};

s3.getSignedUrl("getObject", params, (err, preSignedUrl) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error("error generating presigned URL:", err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "internal server error" });
    } else {
        res.json({ preSignedUrl });
    }
});
```

Now on the frontend, you will be able to access/render the content of the URL created by S3.

Make sure you have right bucket policy and permissions to access the bucket.

Answer (score -1):

your mistake was accessing the `data` directly after `setData`.
the value of `data` will change after rendering.
that's why the value of `data` remains `null`.
if you want to use the fetched value, you need to use the `data` passed as an argument inside the `then`.

```js
  const fetchData = async () => { fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'no-cors', // 'cors' by default
        headers: {
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            'Content-Type': 'text/html',}
        }).then(response => {
            return response.text()
        }).then(data =>
            refIframe.current.setAttribute('src', data)
        );
    }
```

Comment: DV: it's certainly not related to state update delay/batching. `refIframe.current.setAttribute` is executed immediately, without waiting for `fetch` to complete, and here's why it gets effectively set to previous `data` value (`null` initially). This has nothing to do with `setState` at all. Also you decided to remove it from the snippet completely for some reason, why?

Comment: I have an answer to the question you asked.

Comment: I didn't ask any...